# Performance: missing file vs. file exists vs. htaccess

Tags: image, optimization, file-exists

I have a page that serves up thumbnails and occasionally one goes missing. I was about to add a `file_exists()` into the code within the thumbnail loop but then thought that this extra function might slow things down considerably when done on several hundred images. What is the best practice for dealing with broken images in this situation? Perhaps this should be done within the htaccess file?

Ideally any images that aren't found should return a missing.jpg

Thanks in advance!